# Display status bar notification from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing code to display notifications to the user at specific times (just like the Google Calendar app).

I hence created :

- a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `BOOT_COMPLETED`, upon reception it sets an alarm in one minute in order to not overload the device when it is still loading stuff;
- a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to alarms: the first set one minute after `BOOT_COMPLETED`, and the next at the next appointment (like in Google Calendar)

So, typically:

1. `BOOT_COMPLETED` => launch alarm with a one minute delay
2. One minute later => the Receiver sets another alarm for the next appointment
3. Several minutes/hours/days later, the alarm goes off => the Receiver displays a status bar notification

Which means that the status bar notifications are launched from the `BroadcastReceiver`.

I have read in the doc that they should be launched from Activities or Services : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Basics

I'm asking for best practice here. Should I create a `Service` that will be launched by the `BroadcastReceiver`, and which only purpose will be to launch the status bar notification? My code is working, I just want to create clean code as suggested by Google.

Comment: good question, this is making me consider redesigning my current setup which uses the `Alarm`->`BroadcastReceiver`->`Notification` scheme you described :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Notification` from a `BroadcastReceiver`, AFAIK. That should be fairly fast. If `StrictMode` complains about it, then it might be worth worrying about -- otherwise, you should be OK.

Comment: Right. Just to be safe though, the alarm that enventually displays a notification will in fact launch the service, which will display the notification. This will also be future-proof in case I add expensive code before the notification.